# A function that prints it self

Tags: programming

This function prints it self, can someone please explain how it works?

```
Print[ToString[#0][]]& []
```

Comment: Technically it prints `Print[ToString[#0][]]&` as a string and `[]` appended to it. Just replace `Print` with `CellPrint` or copy the output as `InputText` and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: Examine `Print[ToString[#0][]] &[] // Trace`.  Convert the output to input to help distinguish strings from symbols.

Comment: [This](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6104) is related.